# Como validar el tipo de archivo subido para mostrarlo en la app?

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo una duda. En mi proyecto vía un formulario puedo subir archivo de tipo PNG, JPEG y PDF. Sucede que esos archivos debo mostrarlos en pantalla, pero tengo dos formas de mostrarlos ya sea cuando es una imagen o cuando es un documento PDF.

Me gustaría saber de que forma puedo hacer un IF para validar la extensión del archivo y así utilizar una de las formas que tengo para mostrarlos.

Este es el código a implementar en los dos casos:

```
                      {{-- Mostrar en caso de ser un PDF --}}
                          <iframe style="object-fit: contain; width: 100%; height: 500px;"
                             src="{{ Storage::url($imagen->imagen) }}" frameborder="0"></iframe>

                             {{-- Mostrar en caso de ser un JPG o PNG --}}
                            <v-zoomer>
                              <img
                               src="{{ Storage::url($imagen->imagen) }}"
                                style="object-fit: contain; width: 100%; height: 100%;"
                              >
                            </v-zoomer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La funcion `pathinfo()` (https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.pathinfo.php) permite obtener la extension del archivo. Puedes usar @if para mostrar condicionalmente un bloque:

```
{{-- Mostrar en caso de ser un PDF --}}
 <iframe style="object-fit: contain; width: 100%; height: 500px;"
  src="{{ Storage::url($imagen->imagen) }}" frameborder="0"></iframe>

{{-- Mostrar en caso de ser un JPG o PNG --}}
@if(in_array(strtolower(pathinfo($imagen->imagen,PATHINFO_EXTENSION)),["png","jpg"]))
 <v-zoomer>
  <img
   src="{{ Storage::url($imagen->imagen) }}"
   style="object-fit: contain; width: 100%; height: 100%;" >
 </v-zoomer>
@endif
```

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade#if-statements